# Azure + Polymer 2 Application: working on Chrome but not on IE

Tags: azure, internet-explorer, polymer, azure-web-app-service, polymer-2.x

I don't know which parts of the code I have to paste here, but my situation is the following:

- Polymer 2 Application, created from the Starter Kit (surely hybrid, for all the 'basic' web components I used)
- Existing App Service on an Azure subscription
- Polymer build of the es5-bundled version (one of the presets) so to avoid conflicts with IE not recognizing the ES6 syntax
- FTP of the resulting version to the wwwroot directory of an App Service in Azure

Working just out of the box in Chrome and FireFox, NOT working in IE (blank page, no errors).
What I see with the DOM Explorer is that the app element is not loaded: it's shown just as `<my-app></my-app>`

I tried also to install globally the polymer-cli on the Cloud Shell console, restarting the App Service, but with no luck.

In the index.html file, the relevant parts are the usual inclusions:

```
<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="/src/my-app.html">
```

And then I tried also to bring in:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
```

But again, with no luck.

When the problem is only on one browser it's really a nightmare! :-(

Last thing: if I run `polymer serve` both on local master directory, AND on the local `es5-bundled` directory, everybody is working ALSO on IE... So the problems appears to arise only when I try to run the application on an App Service!

## UPDATE

On Aaron Chen request (thanks for your interest, Aaron! :-)) I add that after a long time I get a lot of errors (I repeat, only in IE):
[image: First screen of errors]
[image: Second screen of errors]
What I'm thinking now is that it shouldn't be a problem of configuring the AppService in any way: by default, I'm talking about a 'bunch' of HTML, CSS and JS files, that should run out of the box in any server (and indeed they do, perfectly, on my local Node.js server, and partially, on the AppService, where Chrome and FireFox are working...)

## UPDATE 2

Another question comes to my mind: how can it be that IE (11) needs a ES5-compiled version of the Polymer 2 application, if I can start my local application with a simple `polymer serve` (I mean, on the source code master directory), and locally this works in all browsers, *including* Internet Explorer? The original source code is written in ES6!

## UPDATE 3

The very first error I see comes from an internal Polymer file: /bower_components/polymer/lib/utils/case-map.html, and I'm quite sure that it's the very same file served locally... So it's even more puzzling...

## UPDATE 4

I just made one last test: I deployed the original source code, from the master directory, so without any compilation. The end result is just the same: working in Chrome and FireFox, and not working in IE, with just the same errors. It looks like the compilation phase doesn't have any effect on IE behavior (even if it's still working locally, in IE, both on source and compiled version).

## UPDATE (FINAL, I HOPE)

After a lot of investigation, I narrowed down my problem to this probable bug, let's see what other people say...
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/827

Answer (score 0):

Polymer 2.x and its native elements are written using ES6. You should serve compiled ES5 only to older browsers that don't support ES6.

In this case, you can use the following command to compile all code to ES5.

```
polymer build --js-compile
```

For more infomation, please refer to [Build for production](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/build-for-production#compiling).

Comment: Yes, and if you go down that page, you will see that the es5-bundled preset includes this setting...

Comment: Can you check out the **Console** in IE (F12) and see what that says?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: IE 11.483.15063.0 Update Versions: 11.0.44